# Search string character by character

Tags: c

Okay so bear with me as I'm new to c programming, and programming in general.

I'm in class and the point of this program is to compile it using gcc and point the input for scanf to a text file which we create.

This part is easy, however the problem I have is how can I search the text document character by character to find just for instance the letter 'a'.

Comment: Read the course notes!  You might learn something

Comment: Welcome to SO. You came to the right place but before asking question you should take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `scanf` to read characters.  Use `fgetc`.  Here is some reference material for file I/O.

- [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen)
- [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc)
- [`fclose`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fclose)